# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python-3.x, attributeerror

this is a simple question but could someone give me a hand in getting my code to work? The error happens in line 9 with the error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'. It'd be much appreciated if someone could help me solve this little problem of mine.

```
myFile = ("cat2numbers.txt")
with open("cat2numbers.txt", "wt") as f:   
    print("Writing to the file: ", myFile) # Telling the user what file they will be writing to 
    for i in range(9):
        sentence = input("Please enter a sentence without punctuation ").lower() # Asking the user to enter a sentence
        words = sentence.split() # Splitting the sentence into single words
        positions = [words.index(word) + 1 for word in words]
        f.write(", ".join(map(str, positions))) # write the places to myFile
        myFile.write("\n")
        print("The positions are now in the file")
```

Thank you.

Comment: `myFile` is a string, not the `f` file object. You probably wanted to use `f.write()` instead.

Comment: Please at least post code that is syntactically correct; the parentheses are unbalanced and there is a quote missing.

Comment: I've just realised that myself and plan on fixing it now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're writing correctly in one line and incorrectly in the next:

```
    f.write(", ".join(map(str, positions))) # write the places to myFile
    myFile.write("\n")
```

Try fixing that second line to `f.write("\n")`, or even add the newline in the one write like `f.write(", ".join(map(str, positions)) + "\n")`